# MUI-Datatable expandable rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I am trying to have nested tables. A table and when specific table row is clicked  another table expands right below it(with clear difference from main table) and data related to that specific row will be displayed in that sub table. Each row should be able to render the sub table. 
I am trying to follow their official documentation but failed to do so. 
Below is a code sample that I have copied from their docs.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const columns = ["Name", "Title", "Location", "Age", "Salary"];

    const data = [
      ["Gabby George", "Business Analyst", "Minneapolis", 30, "$100,000"],
      ["Aiden Lloyd", "Business Consultant", "Dallas", 55, "$200,000"],
      ["Jaden Collins", "Attorney", "Santa Ana", 27, "$500,000"],
      ["Franky Rees", "Business Analyst", "St. Petersburg", 22, "$50,000"],
      ["Aaren Rose", "Business Consultant", "Toledo", 28, "$75,000"],
      [
        "Blake Duncan",
        "Business Management Analyst",
        "San Diego",
        65,
        "$94,000"
      ],
      ["Frankie Parry", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Jacksonville", 71, "$210,000"],
      ["Lane Wilson", "Commercial Specialist", "Omaha", 19, "$65,000"],
      ["Robin Duncan", "Business Analyst", "Los Angeles", 20, "$77,000"],
      ["Mel Brooks", "Business Consultant", "Oklahoma City", 37, "$135,000"],
      ["Harper White", "Attorney", "Pittsburgh", 52, "$420,000"],
      ["Kris Humphrey", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Laredo", 30, "$150,000"],
      ["Frankie Long", "Industrial Analyst", "Austin", 31, "$170,000"],
      ["Brynn Robbins", "Business Analyst", "Norfolk", 22, "$90,000"],
      ["Justice Mann", "Business Consultant", "Chicago", 24, "$133,000"],
      [
        "Addison Navarro",
        "Business Management Analyst",
        "New York",
        50,
        "$295,000"
      ],
      ["Jesse Welch", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Seattle", 28, "$200,000"],
      ["Eli Mejia", "Commercial Specialist", "Long Beach", 65, "$400,000"],
      ["Gene Leblanc", "Industrial Analyst", "Hartford", 34, "$110,000"],
      ["Danny Leon", "Computer Scientist", "Newark", 60, "$220,000"],
      ["Lane Lee", "Corporate Counselor", "Cincinnati", 52, "$180,000"],
      ["Jesse Hall", "Business Analyst", "Baltimore", 44, "$99,000"],
      ["Danni Hudson", "Agency Legal Counsel", "Tampa", 37, "$90,000"],
      ["Terry Macdonald", "Commercial Specialist", "Miami", 39, "$140,000"],
      ["Justice Mccarthy", "Attorney", "Tucson", 26, "$330,000"],
      ["Silver Carey", "Computer Scientist", "Memphis", 47, "$250,000"],
      ["Franky Miles", "Industrial Analyst", "Buffalo", 49, "$190,000"],
      ["Glen Nixon", "Corporate Counselor", "Arlington", 44, "$80,000"],
      [
        "Gabby Strickland",
        "Business Process Consultant",
        "Scottsdale",
        26,
        "$45,000"
      ],
      ["Mason Ray", "Computer Scientist", "San Francisco", 39, "$142,000"]
    ];

    const options = {
      filterType: "dropdown",
      responsive: "scroll",
      selectableRows : true,
      renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
        console.log(rowData, rowMeta);
        return (
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell colSpan={rowData.length}>
              Custom expandable row option. Data: {JSON.stringify(rowData)}
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        );
      }
    };

    return (
      <MUIDataTable
        title={"ACME Employee list"}
        data={data}
        columns={columns}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 2019 and this is 2023, I see that you used the "selectableRows " flag instead of the "expandableRows".

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding the expandableRows option?

```
const options = {
  filterType: "dropdown",
  responsive: "scroll",
  selectableRows : true,
  expandableRows: true // Try Adding This
  renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {
    console.log(rowData, rowMeta);
    return (
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell colSpan={rowData.length}>
          Custom expandable row option. Data: {JSON.stringify(rowData)}
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    );
  }
};
```